# Hamiltonian-ization of a dynamic system

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics

On affine space, a sufficiently smooth continuous-time [Hamiltonian dynamic system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_system) $\dot p = \nabla_q H, \dot q = -\nabla_p H$ conserves $H$, preserves the volume form (e.g. if we are looking for ergodicity), and lends itself to a limited physical intuition of position-momentum.

But on the other hand any flow $\dot p = f(p)$ can be seen as the projection of a Hamiltonian system with $H(p, q) = q^t f(p) + g(p)$, where the "gauge" $g$ is any differentiable scalar function.
The resulting Hamiltonian flow is
$$
\begin{align}
\dot p &= f(p) \\
-\dot q &= \left[\nabla f(p)\right] q+ \nabla g(p)
\end{align}
$$

A quick example shows how the $p, q$ system conserves volume in phase space. Let $f$ be multiplication by a negative matrix $A$. Then $p \to 0$ at roughly the same rate at which $q \to \infty$.

Is there a name for this construction, and is there a physical meaning for the variable $q$ and the function $g$? Are there any interesting choices for $g$? (My first instinct is to set $\dot q = 0$, but I am doubt that the "directional derivative" $p \mapsto \left[\nabla f(p)\right] q$ is a conservative function that doesn't depend on $q$.)

Comment: You might want to google "metriplectic". IIRC, this is a way to make "non-Hamiltonian" systems have some kind of symplectic structure.  P J Morrison 2009 J. Phys.: Conf. Ser. 169 012006

Comment: More than 20 years ago I found a similar  concept in some book mentioning a hamiltonian associated to a vetor field attributed to Dirac. I  do not remember the book. I mentioned it at page 7 question 2 of this paper  https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0409594.pdf

Comment: you may be also interested in the remark at the bottom of the page 2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0507516.pdf  and item 3 in page 3 of the latter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This construction is somewhat similar to the Martin-Siggia-Rose formalism for writing expectation values over solutions of a stochastic differential equation
$$
\dot{p}(t)=f(p,t)+\xi(p,t)
$$
with $\xi$ a Gaussian noise with correlation function
$$
\mathbb{E}[\xi(p,t)\xi(p',t')]=G(p,t,p',t')
$$
as a path integral
$$
\mathbb{E}[O[p]]=\int\mathcal{D}p\mathcal{D}q\,O[p]\,e^{-S[p,q]}
$$
with action
$$
S[p,q]=\int \mathrm{d}t\, q\left(\dot{p}-f(p)\right)+\frac{1}{2}\int \mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}t'\,G(q(t),t,q(t'),t')q(t)q(t').
$$
In your situation $G\equiv 0$, so there is no stochastic aspect, and the Lagrangian is just $L=q\dot{p}-qf(p)$, where $p$ is really a generalized position coordinate, whence the Hamiltonian is
$$
H=P\dot{p}-L=(P-q)\dot{p}+qf(p)
$$
where now $P$ is the conjugate momentum to $p$, and identifying $P=q$ yields your ansatz.

As to a physical interpretation of $q$, I don't think there is an obvious one (particularly since $g(q)$ is arbitrary and influences the evolution of $q$).

Comment: I don't know how to contact you, so here it is: Galilee is not just a region mentioned in the Bible it is a real region in Israel :-) North of Israel around the Kineret lake and south of Tverias. Thank you for having fixed my text. BTW if you want to reply to me, use the email in my profile.